# Display txt file in vaadin layout

Tags: file, web-applications, vaadin

I have a txt file that has a couple paragraphs of information (plain text) how would I display this in a textarea.  So far I tried

```
FileResource file = new FileResource(new File("/path/to/file");
TextArea text = new TextArea();
text.setData(file);
```

This did not work

Answer (score 2):

## Incorrect Method Call

Don't use the [`setData()`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractComponent.html#setData(java.lang.Object)) method, but instead the [`setValue(....)`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractTextField.html#setValue(java.lang.String)) method. See the `TextArea` topic in the [Book of Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.textarea.html) and in the [API doc](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/TextArea.html).

This requires a String, so you have to read the text from the file in a String and then use `setValue()` on the TextArea.

The set/getData() methods allows you to save "private" data, which is not used by Vaadin.